# See upload and download speeds of each process

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, internet

Is there a way I can see the internet bandwidth being used by each process on my MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

[**iStat Menus**](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) has this functionality in the Network menu bar item. Each process bandwidth is shown in the Processes section. This is calculated by keeping track of the sent/received bytes (something you can see in Activity Monitor for each process) since the last time period and calculating the bandwidth from this.

[image]

Comment: Why is iStat menu itself using bandwidth?

Comment: @theonlygusti To put the public IP at the top when you show this menu, it makes a connection over the network very briefly when the menu is opened. Due to the way the values are calculated, tiny bandwidth values are over-represented. You can disable the Public IP section of the menu in iStat Menus if you don't wish to use it.